# Programmatically read files and information from a Git repository

Tags: git

I'm on the road right now and started thinking about a project I plan to work on and have a few questions.

I need to be able to read files and information from a (local) Git repository.  So my initial thought is just to run Git commands just to fetch required information I need.  My other thought is that I could read information from the .git directory which I imagine would be more efficient.  Is there any information on this?  Which is more efficient?
Thanks!

Comment: As a general principle I would call the git client to be robust to changes in the data model. This also avoids duplicating all of their data structures logic.

Comment: @APott "So my initial thought is just to run Git commands just to fetch required information I need." If the repo is local, and you're on the road, where are you trying to fetch from, if there is no remote repo available? "My other thought is that I could read information from the `.git` directory which I imagine would be more efficient." How were you planning on "reading" information from that directory? What are you trying to do? Are the normal Git commands via the command line not an option for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May I point your attention to this project: http://libgit2.github.com/
Might be perfectly suited for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I will take a look!

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at [cmd](https://github.com/manojlds/cmd).

It allows you to run git commands via C#, and supports arguments.

It is convention based, so you should be able to run any command that your version of git supports

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't develop on such a platform.  (I know my question wasn't language specific)